# How to control color bar repeating in plotly bar chart?

Tags: python, plotly

I have created a plotted bar chart with Plotly where I noticed that colours are repeated when bars are above 10. I want to have control over this when the length of the x-axis is more than 10, pass a list of colours to be used. There are two orange, two purple, two sky blue, two blue, etc..
[image]

This is the code

```
df = common_helpers.get_dataframe_in_period(df, options)
if "All" not in options["clinic_nurse"]:
   df = df[df["nurse_name"].isin(options["clinic_nurse"])]
per = df.index_date.dt.to_period(options["groupby"]).astype(str)
count = df.pivot_table(
        index=per, columns="nurse_name", values="patient_count", aggfunc="sum"
    ).fillna(0)
    data = []
for col in count.columns:
        data.append(go.Bar(name=col, x=count.index, y=count[col]))
fig = go.Figure(data)
```

Comment: You haven't shown how you're defining that bar chart, but I suspect you must be inadvertently passing in colours. When creating a bar chart without any explicit colour specifications, I'd expect them all to be the default blue colour. You probably want to look at the [`marker_color`](https://plotly.com/python/bar-charts/#customizing-individual-bar-colors) parameter to `graph_objects.Bar`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution and did it finally! Just import plotly.io which will help you modify the main Plotly colours list and append it to whatever number of colours you want to have.

```
import plotly.io as pio
plotly_template = pio.templates["plotly"]
pio.templates["draft"] = plotly_template
additional_colors = ("#ff057e", "#690f54", "#bf6524", "#176b15")
basic_colors = pio.templates["draft"]["layout"]["colorway"]
pio.templates["draft"]["layout"]["colorway"] = basic_colors + additional_colors
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, plotly has up to 10 colors. But you can control and set your favorite color sequency, for example, in px bar parameters by adding:

> color_discrete_sequence=px.colors.qualitative.Dark24

I guess that, if you use go.bar it's possible to use the same trick. Check out this source to find the color sequences with plotly.

https://plotly.com/python/discrete-color/

Updated: here i let you an example where i set my ideal color sequency in a horizontal bar char.

```
fig_bar_stack = px.bar(df2, x="MONTO", y="FECHA",
                                   color="PAGADOR", title=f"SUMA DE LA FACTURACION'", barmode='stack', text='PORCENTAJE',
                                   color_discrete_sequence=px.colors.qualitative.Dark24)
```

Comment: Can you please update your answer with some sample code and explanation? It will help others understand.

Comment: Done! i've written an short example.